# Downvotes getting added to reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

I've encountered a new user today that asked his very first question so badly that he got 4 downvotes as of the moment but when I checked his profile, it was added to his rep instead. See photo.
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If that was the only question they had asked, then one reasonable explanation is that they got 4 downvotes, followed by 1 upvote, followed by another downvote for a net score of -4 on the question.

[image]

The downvotes on a user at 1 rep do not do anything to their rep. So, the first 4 downvotes changed nothing. The first upvote took their rep score to 6, and the final downvote brought it down to 4.

[image]

Comment: Haha, i do a trick sometimes, when i up-vote, then someone down-votes, i undo the up-vote, and redo it again then he will gain 2 rep :P

Comment: @U9-Forward using your vote to invalidate someone else's isn't a good idea...

Comment: I know is stopped